# How to remove double list?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [[1,2,3]]
```

How to remove this double list?
I want to convert this like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: You could just do `a=a[0]`

Comment: like: `a = a[0]`?

Comment: `a = [x for x in i for i in a]`, if you have multiple lists in a list

Answer (score 1):

if a has only one element

```
   b = a[0]
```

if a has many elements

```
   b=[]    
   for i in a :
       b.extend(i)
```